# GitHub Copilot Doesn't Generate Code From Comments in VS Code- extension is enabled

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, github-copilot

I have Github Copilot installed and enabled, but it doesn't generate any code after I type in a comment and press `Enter`. Just goes to next line and nothing happens. I'm on a Mac running VS Code- both up-to-date. Copilot is just installed, so it's up-to-date as well

extension is enabled

[image]

The typeahead suggestions are the only thing that works. But after I press `Tab` and `Enter`, it just goes to new line and nothing happens. No code gets generated. Can't figure out what the problem is.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

It was the VPN that was the problem. Disconnected it and it works now